# Android emulator simulating HTC Desire screen

Tags: android, emulation

i wanna create an emulator  looks like a 「Desire」 screen ,

could someone tell me how to set those configuration ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

screen resolution: 800x480

density: high (240dpi)

OS version: 2.2 / 2.1 (API Level 8/7)